# Return first N% of records in select Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return 33%  of all records in select

```
select id , amount, 'low'
from table 1 
where amount > 1
order by 2;
```

so i need to return first 33% of this records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to enumerate the rows, which in all but the most recent version of MySQL requires variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from (select id , amount, 'low' as col
            from table 1 
            where amount > 1
            order by 2
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where rn <= 0.33 * @rn;  -- @rn is now set to the total number of rows
```

Comment: thanx , its exactly . what . i was trying to achieve